# Strangeness with IEnumerable and OrderBy

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2015, ienumerable

I have a piece of code which seems simple but seems it is not.

```
// Enum values
IEnumerable values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>();

// Sort them by alpha
if (sortByAlpha)
{
    values = (values).OrderBy(i => i.ToString());
}
```

If I write:

```
// Get enum values
IEnumerable values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>();

// Sort them by alpha
if (sortByAlpha)
{
    values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>().OrderBy(i => i.ToString());
}
```

it works.

Why? values in the first piece of code should be the same?
What I am not seeing?
Running this on .Net 4.5.1

Comment: By it works you mean, it compiles?!

Comment: `var` is a great keyword. Use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first code snipped wont compile because [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) is an Extensionmethod of `IEnumerable<T>`, yet you are using `IEnumerable`.

So in order to make it compile, change your first snippet and do this:

```
IEnumerable<TVal> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>();

// Sort them by alpha
if (sortByAlpha)
{
     values = values.OrderBy(i => i.ToString());
 }
```

The difference between `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` is that the latter is basically a more specialized version that knows what elements its dealing with.

For example thats what the Cast method does, it turns an unspecific `IEnumerable` into a `IEnumerable<T>` enabling you to use that OrderBy in the second example.

I recommend you googling abit about this topic.

Comment: How did I not see that? Sometimes you look to long on a piece of code to even see the most logic things. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

The other reply already explains very well on what goes wrong, but I wanted to give some clarification on why it goes wrong in your code. To start here's your code:

```
// Enum values
IEnumerable values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>();
//   ^---- This is where it's going wrong

// Sort them by alpha
if (sortByAlpha)
{
    values = (values).OrderBy(i => i.ToString());
}
```

The `Cast<TVal>()` returns an `IEnumerable<TVal>`, but because you save it as an `IEnumerable` you implicitely cast it. It's similar to doing:

```
IEnumerable values = (IEnumerable) Enum.GetValues(typeof(TVal)).Cast<TVal>();
```

This is entirely valid as `IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` so the cast works, but you lose out on all functionality that `IEnumerable<T>` offers over `IEnumerable`. One of which is the `OrderBy` method.